# JSON- renaming name/value pairs

Tags: json, kohana-3

Hay all,
I am using Kohana 3 and I am attempting to integreate the jquery fullcarlendar plugin. The naming conventions used for this plugin seems to be "title" for the event, "start" for the start date, "allday" for a boolean, and so on.

After querying I generated a json string like

```
[{"eventdate":"2011-02-05 06:15:35","name":"EBS, Heriot Watt Graduation Ceremony"},{"eventdate":"2011-02-05 06:16:20","name":"Heriot Watt University Edinburgh Business School Graduation Ceremony 2011"}]
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
DB::select('start'=>'simpleevent.eventdate', 'title'=>'simpleevent.name')                     
                    ->from('simpleevent')
                    ->where('YEAR("eventdate")', '=', $todayasarray[0])
```

Basically after the query I get an array of arrays in PHP which is then used in

```
json_encode($myArray)
```

So can I rename the "name" for each name/value pair?

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB::select(array('simpleevent.eventdate', 'start'), array('simpleevent.name', 'title'))                     
                ->from('simpleevent')
                ->where( /*condition*/)
```

Comment: There is more to my conditions, the query is functioning as i want it to. The only problem is generating a json string with the correct naming convention. That is where i have "eventgdate" I need "start" and where I have "name" I need "title"

Comment: He showed you, you have to use `array('realname', 'alias')` to do a `realname AS alias`.

Comment: Thanks Dusan, your approach was more efficient as with a large data set, the time complexity of my algorithm was not very good.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, basically after creating the json as a string on my action I used the php str_replace() function as follows.

```
$oldnames = array("name","eventdate");
$newnames = array("title","start");
$v->jsonData = str_replace($oldnames, $newnames, $jsondata);
```

This is an option only if you cannot make the alias change as shown above by Dusan